# The missing preamble element

Tags: html

I find it somewhat strange that there is no preamble element in HTML. This means that if an article with a preamble is rendered without or with the default CSS there is no way for the reader to tell the preamble and the body text apart. Does anyone know of a best practice in this case? Of course I can add a preamble class, like in

```
<p class="preamble">New technologies will enable a breakthrough in...</p>
```

but that will not solve the fundamental problem.

Comment: HTML is not intended to mirror print-based or other "publishing" conventions.  In the solutions listed below, they're still not a direct correlation.  Even in a semantic sense, a "preamble" is a fairly narrow concept in the scope of hypertext.

Comment: Disagree with @GalacticCowboy. Preamble has a clear semantic meaning in publishing. Web is publishing. It's clearly a missing tag.

Comment: @Teson That's fine, you're entitled to do so. But note that this question and my comment predated the ratification of HTML 5 by approximately 3 years, and the CSS 3 "media queries" specification by more than a year. Both of those things brought the worlds of HTML and publishing much closer together. And in any case, my comment clearly stated that I was speaking solely about hypertext, and your objection is based on publishing. I stand by my statement - there are lots of "publishing" concepts that don't make sense as *stand alone* elements in HTML.

Answer (score 5):

If i understand your question correctly, you're looking for the `<details>`, `<summary>` and `<article>` tags in HTML5, perhaps:

```
<details open="true">
<summary>
A Bunch of Latin used by Printers...
</summary>
<article>
Lorem Ipsum Si Dolor Amet...
</article>
</details>
```

Forgive me if i misunderstand your question.

EDIT: Thanks to Alochi for noting that "open" must be set to "true" for the article to display by default.

Comment: That will, in a fully HTML5 compliant browser, by default, hide the article entirely. I doubt the OP wants that, and I suspect that details/summary are not the right elements here. However, I recommend that if they are to be used, that the `open` attribute is added to the details element so that the page starts with the article displayed. See http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/interactive-elements.html#attr-details-open for more info.

Answer (score 1):

There's a new element in HTML5 called `<header>` which is supposed to do that.  Not sure how prevalent it is, though.

Answer (score 0):

As of HTML5 you can use the `<section>` element:

```
<section class="preamble">
  preamble text...
</section>
<section class="text">
  text...
</section>
```